# Video cards for multiple monitors

Tags: hardware-rec, graphics-card, vga

I thin that the commom scenarios for multiple monitors is one video card with 2+ video outs or 1 PCI-express video card and 1+ PCI video cards.

What video cards have good prices in both situations?

Comment: what will they be used for?  For browsing/office apps you can find very cheap ones, but they won't be any good for gaming.

Comment: browsing/office apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PCI-Express cards tend to come cheaper than PCI (due to sales volumes), you may want to consider getting a motherboard that can take multiple PCI-Ex cards if you do not have an existing motherboard you have to work with.

Even if you already have a motherboard, depending on what you are doing you may want to look at dual PCI-Ex as an option, since it may be a bit cheaper than PCI-Ex + PCI, and give you a newer motherboard at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Next option is [Matrox Dual2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/)

Best way how connect two monitors (LCD) to PC is graphic card with two DVI connectors (best picture for LCD). Old cards had problem with resolution for big LCDs, but this is gone.

But, if you have LCD with big resolution, like 1920x1200, you need card with Dual Link DVI.

I think, future is [DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort)